Baking an fk animation to the same characters IK rig?
In Motionbuilder, I can quickly bake an animation on a character's FK bone rig to a generated IK rig and back. This allows for seamlessly switching between an fk and ik animation workflow.
All I can find for Blender is snapping a single pose back and forth, but not how to do this for animations.
This is such an essential tool for animators, which I hope is available in Blender as well? Maybe via addon? I've looked at MHX and Rigify ik rigs, but I don't see that same functionality in there. Any idea on how to do that in Blender?


Some Blender rigs, like all Rigify IK/FK chains, have a built in functionality  for baking from IK to FK and Viceversa, which appears whenever a bone of the chain is selected.
If a rig doesn't have it, you can easily add some copy transform constraints to bones and then bake their effect on the whole animation using the Pose menu > Pose > Animation > Bake action (Visual Keying, Clear Constraints, Overwrite current).

